# Webpacker creates huge node_modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I created a new project with Rails 5.1 and I want to use webpacker to manage my react dependencies. The problem is after installing webpacker it creates a huge 130Mb+ dir node_modules with every possible node_package. This does not make sense as default behavior. How can I configure Webpacker to only keep the packages I'm actually using. I have searched for this issue in every way I could and I did not see any answers that made sense

Comment: What packages do you have listed in `package.json`? These `node_modules` could be just dependencies to your packages. I'd say `node_modules` is famous for being huge for no reason.

Comment: @TamerShlash after a lot of digging around it looks I may be misunderstanding how yarn works. I thought all packages should be kept in a global node_modules dir but it looks like it keeps a local copy in the project as well. This directory can become huge. I think I may just exclude this dir from my GIT repo but it still seems like a strange way to handle it.

Comment: `node_modules` MUST be git ignored. There's no reason to include it, especially since you are using Yarn which has `yarn.lock` to make sure versions are the same.

Comment: @TamerShlash thank! it all makes sense now, I was looking at it from the wrong point of view

Answer (score 3):

Install what you need via yarn add, they will be listed in your `package.json`. Once you run `assets:precompile` (which will also run `webpacker:compile`) or just `webpacker:compile`, the public folder will be populated the compiled assets you are going to need to run the app.

Like Tamer says, node_modules should be in your `.gitignore` file. In dev, you will see all the node modules due to existing dependencies but that doesn't mean they are going to be used.

In summary, don't worry and rely on yarn.